# Access morphedByMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel

do you know how to access morphedByMany relationship?

I got this api route, where when I access this path I will be presented with all articles where certain TAG is attached:

```
Route::get('/tags/{tag:slug}', 'Tags\TagController@index');
```

Tag model:

```
  public function articles()
    {
        return $this–>morphedByMany(Article::class, 'taggable' );
    }
```

Controller:

```
return $tag->load(['articles']);
```

I got this error: Call to undefined function App\morphedByMany()

Comment: Try `return $this–>morphMany(Article::class, 'taggable' );`

Comment: Hey there, I got same problem Call to undefined function App\morphMany(

Comment: What is the namespace for Article Model?

Comment: Article.php has namespace App;